# Can i use (?=...)|(?<=...) instead of standalone (?=...) or (?<=...) in all cases?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

My question is

Can I use `lookahead|lookbehind` instead of standalone `lookahead` or `lookbehind` in all cases?

I just think

`(?=...)|(?<=...)` is similar to `\b`

In term of we don't need to tell that we want to use left or right word boundary (or look behind or ahead) but just want to say that "any of them".

From this question [What's the difference between \b and \>, \< in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723018/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-in-regex):

We will see that we can use `\b` instead of `\<` and `\>`

And for `(?=...)|(?<=...)`, I'm not sure it is safe or not to say that we can use `(?=...)|(?<=...)` instead of standalone `(?=...)` or `(?<=...)` in all cases.

If you have any example that `(?=...)|(?<=...)` can not use instead of `(?=...)` or `(?<=...)` please show me.

Answer (score 0):

Sequential lookarounds are a logical AND.
If you put them between alternations they are logical OR's.

You can nest lookarounds.

```
(?=  a | (?<! b ) ) [^c]
```

which is equivalent to

```
(?: (?= a ) | (?<! b ) ) [^c]
```

The thing to remember is that lookarounds are safe from backtracking.
And when you enter a lookaround it maintains a separate search position.

Comment: Yes, And this is why we don't need `&` (logical operator) in `regex` because all text or command that align on the same line of `regex` are actually connected with `&` already. Right?

Comment: @terces907 - the logic is almost the same, and scoping applies. The difference is that quantifiers _can_ cause the engine to backtrack to a different control path.